# How can I use OR in filters with Speedment

Tags: java, speedment

How can I use OR when I want to filter Speedment streams? How do I write a stream with users that are either from NY, NJ or PA?

```
users.stream()
    .filter(User.STATE.equals("NY"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

This produces a list of users from NY only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case there are at least two ways to go:
  a) use `Predicate::or`
  b) Use an `in` predicate

#### Predicate::or

```
users.stream()
    .filter(
        User.STATE.equals("NY")
        .or(User.STATE.equals("NJ"))
        .or(User.STATE.equals("PA"))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

#### in() Predicate

```
users.stream()
    .filter(User.STATE.in("NY", "NJ", "PA"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would use the latter solution which looks nicer in my opinion.